# font-weight 300 makes text italic in safari

Tags: css, safari, sass, safari-web-inspector

I'm importing

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900')
```

and using

```
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

and I end with having all my text italic in Safari on my iMac.
In Safari on my MacBook (exact same version) or in Chrome on my iMac it is normal as it should.
I don't load any extra stylesheet in the Safari Extensions.
What could lead to this italic text?

Comment: is it possible you have Roboto installed as a system font on your iMac?  Google fonts will use locally installed fonts if available over web fonts and that could be causing issues. https://developers.google.com/fonts/faq

Comment: That solved it! Thank you!

Comment: No problem. I've been down that same road. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
font-style: normal;
```

This may solve your issue.

Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-style.asp

Comment: No, it does not. This would solve my issue if I had it on the other machines as well, but I don't.